# ASP.NET - Get control in RowCommand event

Tags: asp.net

Trying to access a RequiredFieldValidator control that's inside a GridView in the RowCommand event and having trouble.

Here's the partial GridView code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewTextbox" TextMode="Password" Text='<%#Eval("WebPassword") %>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWebPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Text='<%#Eval("WebPassword") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
            ControlToValidate="txtWebPassword" Display="None" ErrorMessage='<%# Constants.Strings.PasswordRequired %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddWebPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddPassword" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
            ControlToValidate="txtAddWebPassword" Display="None" ErrorMessage='<%# Constants.Strings.PasswordRequired %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As you can see, there's a RFV for the EditTemplate and FooterTemplate.  My issue is this; when the page loads, it has all the records in it, including an emtpy row at the bottom (Footer).  If I click Edit on a populated row, the data is populated correctly, then when I hit UPDATE, I get all the error messages from the FOOTER RFV's firing off, which isn't correct.  So, in the RowCommand event, I'd like to attempt this:  If the user clicks the EDIT button, then disable all the RFV's in the footer row (the add new row), if they click anything else, enable them.

Ideas?

Sorry, meant to put this in the first time.  In the RowCommand event, I am able to find the control but when I set the properties to something bogus, it seems to get overridden later, by the RowDataBound event:

```
            RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)gvUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("rfvAddWebLogin");
            rfv.ControlToValidate = string.Empty;
            rfv.ErrorMessage = "sdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg";
            rfv.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: What is the empty row for - do you actually need it?

Comment: yeah, the empty row is for inserting a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different  [ValidationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfieldbase.validationgroup.aspx) in your `EditItemTemplate` and `FooterItemplate`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" CausesValidation="False" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"  runat="server"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" ValidationGroup="UpdateUser" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"  runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnInsert" ValidationGroup="InsertUser" Text="Add" CommandName="Insert" runat="server" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewTextbox" TextMode="Password"
            Text='<%#Eval("WebPassword") %>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWebPassword" ValidationGroup="UpdateUser" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Text='<%#Eval("WebPassword") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" ValidationGroup="UpdateUser" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
            ControlToValidate="txtWebPassword" Display="None" ErrorMessage='<%# Constants.Strings.PasswordRequired %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddWebPassword" ValidationGroup="InsertUser" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddPassword" ValidationGroup="InsertUser" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
            ControlToValidate="txtAddWebPassword" Display="None" ErrorMessage='<%# Constants.Strings.PasswordRequired %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx#aspnett19_vldcntredtuics_topic7

**Note**: If you're using `ValidationSummaries`, you need to add the appropriate `ValidationGroup` to every ValidationSummary. If you leave this property blank, only controls without a specified ValidationGroup will be listed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.validationgroup.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.  It should also be noted that if you are using a ValidationSummary control (like I am) then you'll need to set the ValidationGroup property as well.

Comment: Oh, and you'll need a ValidationSummary for every ValidationGroup you create; unless I'm missing something there.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for editing. You are right, you need a separate ValidationSummary for every ValidationGroup(editd my answer). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.validationgroup.aspx